# Loop through categories and posts of a custom post type in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a custom post type called `faq` in WordPress and I've created a few categories for it - like "Billing" and "Shipping". My end goal is to create multiple FAQ "Posts" so I can add them to our search API. However, I'm stuck on trying to loop through the post categories and display the FAQ's under each category **if the category has FAQ posts**:

Here's my code:

```php
$category_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => "ASC",
);
$categories = get_categories( $category_args ); // Get all Categories

foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

    $post_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'faq',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'numberposts' => -1,
    );

    $posts = get_posts( $post_args ); // Get all FAQ post_types from categories


    // Here's where I'm getting stuck: If a category has faq posts:

    // 1.) Display the category title
    // 2.) Loop through the posts 
}
```

Any ideas on how to modify this code to output like so:

```
// Billing
// - Billing Question 1
// - Billing Question 2

// Shipping
// - Shipping Question 1
// - Shipping Question 2

etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar code, but with custom categories as well. So lets first try this adaption of code which works with regular posts and categories.

The trick is to use `WP_Query` function, while not forgetting to `wp_reset_query()` afterwards.

```php
$category_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => "ASC",
);
$categories = get_categories($category_args); // Get all Categories

foreach ($categories as $category) {

    // $post_args = array(
    //  'post_type' => 'faq',
    //  'post_status' => 'publish',
    //  'numberposts' => -1,
    // );

    $args = array(
        'cat' => $category->term_id,
        // 'post_type' => 'faq',     // maybe?
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    );

    $posts = new WP_Query($args);


    if ($posts->have_posts()) {
        echo "<h1>" . $category->name ."</h1>";
        while ($posts->have_posts()) {
            $posts->the_post();
            echo "<h2>" . get_the_title() . "</h2>";

        }
    }
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks for this, the `post_type` was required in my case. Thanks again!